# How to build python package without uploading to pypi and to install within local

Tags: python, package, local

I am following the below link to build python package 
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

when it comes to installation pip install package.whl, I get the error as

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application

But how do we avoid this error, Is there anyway to skip pip searching for distribution?

Comment: Why your application has pip in dependencies. And why in fixed version?

Comment: I don't think the error has anything to do with pypi. Do you even have `pip` installed? What does `pip --version` give you?

Comment: I am using python 3.7 which comes with pip3.7. And yes it seems like I have a problem here. Whenj I try pip3.7 --version, I get the same error.

Comment: Below is my pip3.7-script.py
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==19.0.3','console_scripts','pip3.7'
__requires__ = 'pip==19.0.3'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==19.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip3.7')()
    )

Answer (score 0):

I had my pip screwed with windows --upgrade pip.

On my investigation found that, when I did that upgrade my pip-script.py was deleted (bug in pip/windows)

"easy_install pip" fixed that by installing pip-script.py again.

thanks to Ricky Kim for pointing pip --version, that provoked more questions to find the problem.